# How to understand method reference in Java8 when using BiConsumer

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have a sample code like below, I can write it and know what will it work like.
But I still have some difficult on understand what java did that convert something using :: to a typical method.

```
.collect(ConcurrentHashMap::newKeySet,Set::add,Set::addAll)
```

The first parameter is `Supplier<R> supplier`, I can understand this like there is a Supplier instance which `get()` method has same implementation with `ConcurrentHashMap::newKeySet`.

The second and third parameter are 'BiConsumer', if I use lambda expression, I will write something like `(a,b)->a.add(b)`. when I wrote `Set::add`, how they know convert first parameter a to Set and then invoke `add()` method on it.

Definition of BiConsumer is a simple method with two parameter.

If there is some like, I won't feel hard to understand:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
Consumer<String> consumer = set::add;
```

I just cannot understand how they know to invoke the add method on first parameter.